# Save file in successfully created folder: "file name or path doesn't exist"

Tags: excel, vba

This code creates a folder, but it does not save the file in it.

It shows an alert message

> file name or path doesn't exist

```vb
startPath = "C:\Users\OsmonBek\Documents\macros"
myName1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Text

Dim folderPathWithName As String
folderPathWithName = startPath & "\" & myName1

If Dir(folderPathWithName, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
    MkDir folderPathWithName
Else
End If

' Save File
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
  "folderPathWithName & \legend F22 A&P report " & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY") & ".xlsx" _
  , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: I'd say, just a typo ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have your quote characters wrong. Probably you mean `folderPathWithName & "\legend F22 A&P report "` so you get the content of the path variable into the filename.

Write the filename into an intermediate variable, that helps finding such errors:

```
' Save File
Dim newFileName As String
newFileName = folderPathWithName & "\legend F22 A&P report " & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY") & ".xlsx" 

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= newFileName _ 
                    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```